# How to write ES search queries for complex documents structure?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have the following documents and structure:

Document 1:

```
{
'id': '1',
'data': {
    'parents': [],
    'people': []
 }
```

Document 2:

```
{
'id': '2',
'data': {
    'parents': ["one", "two"],
    'people': [{'relationship': 'boss', 'ids': ['1']}, {'relationship': 'friends', 'ids': ['1']}]
 }
```

Document 3:

```
{
'id': '3',
'data': {
    'parents': ["one", "two"],
    'people': [{'relationship': 'boss', 'ids': ['1', '2']}, {'relationship': 'friends', 'ids': ['1', '2']}]
 }
}
```

I want to delete a document given an id and then delete any relationships with document in other documents.

So given id = '1', document 1 is deleted, and document 2 and 3's relationship entires that include '1' are updated to not include '1' anymore; so after document 1 is deleted, we have the following:

Document 2:

```
{
'id': '2',
'data': {
    'parents': ["one", "two"],
    'people': []
 }
```

Document 3:

```
{
'id': '3',
'data': {
    'parents': ["one", "two"],
    'people': [{'relationship': 'boss', 'ids': ['2']}, {'relationship': 'friends', 'ids': ['2']}]
 }
}
```

I am struggling writing the ES queries because the document's structure is a complex one;

What I have tried so far are the following:

```
{ 'query': { 'match': { 'id.keyword': '1' } } }
```

```
{ 'terms': {data.people.ids.keyword: ['1'], 'minimum_should_match': 1 } }
```

but they do not work, nor do they throw an error.

Comment: Could you please share your mapping? Doesn't seem like you're using the default one.

Comment: @ilvar thank you for your reply! I am actually not sure what do u mean by mapping. When a new elasticsearch data point is inserted it is in the following format: {
'id': <string>,
'data': {
    'parents': <list of strings>,
    'people': <list>
 } where people is a list of dict with relationship and ids fields with string and list of strings

Comment: Where are you getting `id.keyword` ?

Comment: @ilvar there is id field in the document, so I thought using .keyword is how u refer to a field; so if the field was bla instead of id, will be using bla.keyword

Comment: No it should be defined in the mapping in a special way. Until that you should use `id` and `data.people.ids`

Comment: great, will try it out, thanks! @ilvar

Comment: @ilvar, thank you, it worked! Not sure how can I give you points, but if nothing else, have a great day and God bless!